# Ag-Grid : Modify data in one grid while applying filter in another Grid

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

I have 2 grids side by side as per design and both will have same no.of rows. i need to apply filter in one column of grid1 and same amount rows should be in both the grids after applying filter also.

Component.ts

```
 GridOptions = <GridOptions>{
   enableFilter: true,
   rowSelection: 'multiple',
   enableSorting: false,
   enableColResize: true,
   singleClickEdit: true,
   animateRows: true,
   headerHeight: 50,
   rowClass: 'rowClass',
   headerClass: 'GridHeader',
   overlayNoRowsTemplate: " ",
   context: {
     componentParent: this
   },    
   onFilterModified: this.GridFilter
};

GridColumnDefs = [{
  headerName: "Student Name", field: "name", width: 90, editable: true, 
  filter: 'agTextColumnFilter'
},];

releaseFilter(params: any) {
  var data = params.api.getRenderedNodes()
}
```

I got the filtered rows of grid1 but dont know how to set the filtered index for the second grid. Thanks in advance

Comment: Please consider creating a Minimal Sample StackBlitz Sample replicating this issue,

Comment: this is not an issue. dont know how to implementation. After filter if the grid1 has two records then grid2 should have two records

Comment: Sure. Just click [here](https://stackblitz.com/fork/angular) and you'll be good to go.